# problem with shipment methods

Tags: magento-1.7, checkout, shipment

For our sport supply products (still in testing mode). Main interface / user language will be Dutch.

We have put a minimum order amount of ERU 50 to receive free shipments. When I test with my Cart filled with products worth a value over EUR50 it still prompt me as part of check out procedure the shipment methods Free Shipment and Flat Rate. In the tab configuration / shipment methods / free shipping i put the field  to 50.

Answer (score 2):

This is because at that moment both free shipping and flat rate method applies. 
To display only free shipping if the order amount is 50 or more you need to use shopping cart rule. Follow the below steps for it

1. Enable Flat rate and disable Free shipping
2. Goto Promotions->shopping Cart Price rule from Magento admin
3. Create a new rule for free shipping. Check the screenshot for how to do it.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

Save and apply the rule it will work

Comment: Great feedback Dexter..Thxs for that. Since we would like also clients to order items based on based on reimbursements (so we will ship the ordered items and at the moment of delivery by postal service company the items will be paid for). Is this an extra feature that needs to be put on enable or should I simply add an extra shipment method extension from a 3rd party?

Comment: Please ask it in another question so you could get better replies as no one will read the comments. Also please ask the answer as accepted so the question could be closed.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add this rule into your design/theme/template/checkout/shipping_method/available.phtml

so before it starts calling and styling the different methods you can use this rule to achieve your result (you just need to know the method name for the free delivery.

```
<?php
    if ( array_key_exists('freedelivery', $_shippingRateGroups )) {
        $_shippingRateGroups = array('freedelivery' => $_shippingRateGroups['freedelivery']);
    }
    ?>
```